# Integer solution, then it has a solution in $F_p$ for all $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Consider a system $AX = B$ of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns, where $A$ and $B$ have integer entries. Prove or disprove: If the system has an integer solution, then it has a solution in $F_p$ for all $p$.

Attempt:

$AX=B$ i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j=b_i$, $i=1(1)n$.

Then under $F_p$, $\overline{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j}=\overline{b_i}$, $i=1(1)n$, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\overline{a_{ij}}\space\space\overline{x_j}=\overline{b_i}$, $i=1(1)n$. Then $(\overline{x_1},\overline{x_1},\dots,\overline{x_{n-1}},\overline{x_n})'\in F_p$ is a solution of the equation. Then the statement is true.

---

My question: 1."*$n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns*" is important here? I mean if I use $m$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns, will that be a problem?

2. [In this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784593/linear-system-of-equations-over-a-finite-field) OP talk about *homomorphism*, why that is important? Is my solution wrong?

**Edit:**

The second question I did is not really a issue here. Of course the homomorphic map $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ **is important**. Otherwise I if not homomorphic I can not write $\overline{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\overline{a_{ij}}\space\space\overline{x_j}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The number of linear equations is unimportant. Indeed linearity is unimportant. The argument works just as well for systems of polynomial equations.

Comment: Re homomoprhism: Without considering the standard homomoprhism $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb F_p$, i doesn't even make senseto speak about a solution of $AX=B$ in $\Bbb F_p$ as $A,B$ are not matrices with entries in $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: oho!!! you are right @HagenvonEitzen ...

Comment: Re homomorphism: Your overlines represent the homomorphism in question: $a$ is an integer, $\bar a$ is an element of $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur ... that was just a silly question I did.

Comment: Not at all. It might have an easy solution, but that doesn't mean the question was silly. It's also worth noting that you're using the defining properties of homomorphisms when you go from $\overline{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j}$ to $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\overline{a_{ij}}\space\space\overline{x_j}$, which is why the concept of "homomorphism" is indeed important, even though the word itself may be skipped, as you've done.